# Cannot print more than one sheet from webpage using HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I have created a webpage using HTML5 Canvas and a series of Javascript commands. The webpage is formatted deliberately so that if sent to a printer, it will automatically throw a new page at the right place - in other words it looks like the intended printed sheets, laid end to end. The webpage looks perfect but when I send it to the printer, the first sheet prints correctly but the subsequent sheets are blank.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

If the browser, which you do not mention, does not support printing `<canvas>` over several pages do the following:

- Split `<canvas>` to several `<canvas>` parts where there is one per page
- Use Print CSS to format the pages for printing http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

You also do not show any code or the resulting HTML creating this phenomenom, so it is pretty much impossible to guess what is your exact problem

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've tried this with Firefox, Chrome, Safari and all behave indentically. From your first bullet point I suspect there's an underlying "fact of life" - a canvas equates to a printed page. I've discovered the page-break:always attribute for <p> and using that and <div>, managed to solve it: and to wrap separate canvases and that seems to work.

Comment: Here's the outline of the code that works:

<div style=position:absolute;top:10pt;left:10pt>
   <canvas id="myCanvas" width=800 height=200 > </canvas>
    <script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
…. Javascript drawing commands….
</script>
</div>

<p style=page-break-before:always> 

<div style=position:relative;top:10pt;left:10pt>
   <script>
canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
…. Javascript drawing commands….
</script>
</div>